# IE8 Unable to get value of the property 'src': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, internet-explorer-8, push, tagname

This has been stressing me out for 3 nights now...I don't know why it works in IE9 but not IE8. I keep getting this error when I run it on IE8:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'src': object is null or undefined

when I try to debug I get this line being the cause ->

```
        var map_locations = [], container = document.getElementById('renting-map-js'), 
        c = container.children, l = c.length, i, obj, p, m, j;

        //loop through all child nodes
        for ( i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            obj = {};

            //highlights this line
            obj.img = c[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src; 

            p = c[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
            m = p.length;
            for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
                obj[p[j].className] = p[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
            map_locations[i] = obj;
            console.log(obj);
        }
```

​

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EgzKv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE6-8, .children [also returns comment nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children). Since comment nodes can't have children, they also can't contain images that have a src attribute, causing your error.

jQuery can fix this:

```
var map_locations = [],
    container = document.getElementById('renting-map-js'),
    c = $(container).children().get(),
    l = c.length,
    i, obj, p, m, j;

//loop through all child nodes
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    obj = {};
    obj.img = c[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
    p = c[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
    m = p.length;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    obj[p[j].className] = p[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
    map_locations[i] = obj;
    console.log(obj);
}​
```

Comment: You just saved my life! Forever grateful mate!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this problem because of comment nodes, you just need to ignore them. Easiest solution if you do not use jQuery - just add check for nodeType, and ignore all instead of 1 (Element node):

```
var map_locations = [], container = document.getElementById('renting-map-js'), 
c = container.children, l = c.length, i, obj, p, m, j;

//loop through all child nodes
for ( i = 0; i < l; i++) {

    // Ignore non-element nodes.
    if(c[i].nodeType != 1)
        continue;

    obj = {};

    //highlights this line
    obj.img = c[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src; 

    p = c[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
    m = p.length;
    for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
        obj[p[j].className] = p[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
    map_locations[i] = obj;
    console.log(obj);
}
```

More about nodeType property - http://help.dottoro.com/ljkadgoo.php